# facebook upload photo along with description and caption in iphone

Tags: iphone, facebook, post

I want to upload the image to the facebook.
I could upload the photo along with caption. I also want to upload the description

I tried adding the key "description" to the dictionary. But it didn't work.

Is it possible to upload the description as well?

Following is the code i am using..

```
- (void)postToWall {

    FBRequest *uploadPhotoRequest = [FBRequest request];

    NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(saveImage, 1.0); 
    UIImage  *image_  = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData]; 

    FBPermissionDialog* dialog1 = [[[FBPermissionDialog alloc] init] autorelease];
    dialog1.delegate = self;
    dialog1.permission = @"photo_upload";
    [dialog1 show];

    NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    @"Hey!!!!!!", @"caption",
                                    @"I Own It..", @"description", //This didn't post the description..
                                    nil];


    if (nil!=image_)
        [uploadPhotoRequest call:@"photos.upload" params:params dataParam:(NSData*)image_]; 
    NSLog(@"image uploaded"); 
    [image_ release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1488/how-to-use-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app